# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to change the state created with the useState hook when clicked. But I do not understand this mistake.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined'). I do not understand why this happens after setState (state.activeQuestion + 1)

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import classes from './Quiz.module.css'
import ActiveQuiz from '../../components/ActiveQuiz/ActiveQuiz'

export default function Quiz () {

    const [state, setState] = useState(
 {  activeQuestion: 0,     
    quiz: [
           {
               question: 'Якого коліру небо',
               rightAnswerId: 2,
               id: 1,
               answers: [
                   {text: 'чорний', id: 1},
                   {text: 'синій', id: 2},
                   {text: 'червоний', id: 3},
                   {text: 'зелений', id: 4}
               ]  
           },
           {
            question: 'Якому році 2 світова',
            rightAnswerId: 3,
            id: 2,
            answers: [
                {text: '1954', id: 1},
                {text: '1948', id: 2},
                {text: '1949', id: 3},
                {text: '1918', id: 4}
            ]  
        }
       ],}
    )

    const onAnswerClickHandler = answerId => {
        console.log('Answer Id: ', answerId);
        setState(state.activeQuestion + 1)
    }

    return(
        <div className={classes.Quiz}>
            <div className={classes.QuizWraper}>
                <h1> Дайте відповідь на всі Питання </h1>
                <ActiveQuiz 
                    answers={state.quiz[state.activeQuestion].answers}
                    question={state.quiz[state.activeQuestion].question}
                    onAnswerClick={onAnswerClickHandler}
                    quizLength={state.quiz.length}
                    answerNumber={state.activeQuestion + 1}                   
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBxQY.png)

Comment: The correct statement is:```setState(prev=>({...prev,activeQuestion : prev.activeQuestion + 1}))```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, with onAnswerClickHandler you are changing the shape of your state. Your state is an object and holds different values.

```
 const onAnswerClickHandler = answerId => {
        console.log('Answer Id: ', answerId);
        setState(state.activeQuestion + 1) 
    }
```

in here you are changing your state to a number:

```
state = {object stuff here}//
//after you call the function
state = 0 + 1 // all the other stuff is gone
```

as @cybercoder commented, you should use spread operator:

```
setState(prev=>({...state, activeQuestion : prev.activeQuestion + 1})) –
```

with spread operator, you copy all the data that your object contains and you only update the necessary value that you want to update

Comment: My pleasure. It's really good that you are asking these questions. It's the only/best way to learn. I've been there not so long ago